# Invalid PKCS #7 block padding when using Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++, pkcs#7

We are using cryptopp library. We are using the below coding. Encryption is working file without any issue and we are able to get the cipher text. But getting an error while decrypting as "Block padding found". What could be the issue...?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

#include "cryptlib.h"
#include "filters.h"
#include "files.h"
#include "modes.h"
#include "hex.h"
#include "aes.h"
#include "osrng.h"
using namespace CryptoPP;
using CryptoPP::AutoSeededRandomPool;

class cspl_crypto{

public:
  cspl_crypto();
  byte* generate_block(int size);
  char* encrypt_rijndael(byte[], byte[], int, char*, int);
  char* decrypt_rijndael(byte[], byte[], int, char*, int);
  string readFile();
  void writeFile(string);
};

cspl_crypto::cspl_crypto()
{

}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
  vector<byte> plain;
  cspl_crypto ccrypto;
  AutoSeededRandomPool prng;

    byte key[AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH];
    prng.GenerateBlock(key, sizeof(key));

    byte iv[AES::BLOCKSIZE];
    prng.GenerateBlock(iv, sizeof(iv));
```

Converting string to char *

```
  string str("testing"); //ccrypto.readFile()
char plainArray[str.size()];
strcpy(plainArray, str.c_str());

char* cipher  = ccrypto.encrypt_rijndael(key, iv, sizeof(key), plainArray, 
sizeof(plainArray));

//char cipherCharArray[cipherText.size()];
// strcpy(cipherCharArray, cipherText.c_str());

char* recover = ccrypto.decrypt_rijndael(key, iv, sizeof(key), cipher, 
sizeof(cipher));

// cout << "Recovered text: " << recoverText << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Encryption Block:

```
char* cspl_crypto::encrypt_rijndael(byte key[], byte iv[], int keysize, char 
plainText[], int plainTextSize){
    vector<byte> cipher;

       std::vector<byte> plain(plainText, plainText + plainTextSize);

    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc;
enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, keysize, iv, keysize);

// Make room for padding
cipher.resize(plain.size()+AES::BLOCKSIZE);
ArraySink cs(&cipher[0], cipher.size());

ArraySource(plain.data(), plain.size(), true,
        new StreamTransformationFilter(enc, new Redirector(cs)));

// Set cipher text length now that its known
cipher.resize(cs.TotalPutLength());
    char returnValue[cipher.size()];
    copy(cipher.begin(), cipher.end(), returnValue);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Decyption Block:

```
char* cspl_crypto::decrypt_rijndael(byte key[], byte iv[], int keysize, char 
cipher[], int size ){
 std::vector<byte> v(cipher, cipher + size);
 vector<byte> recover;
  CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
  dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, keysize, iv, keysize);

  // Recovered text will be less than cipher text
  recover.resize(v.size());
  ArraySink rs(&recover[0], recover.size());

  ArraySource(v.data(), v.size(), true,
    new StreamTransformationFilter(dec, new Redirector(rs)));

  // Set recovered text length now that its known
  recover.resize(rs.TotalPutLength());

        char returnValue[recover.size()];
        copy(recover.begin(), recover.end(), returnValue);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Library:

```
string cspl_crypto::readFile(){

  string line;
  string returnValue = "";
  ifstream myfile ("N07.txt");
  if (myfile.is_open())
  {
    while ( getline (myfile,line) )
    {
      returnValue +=  line + '\n';
    }
    myfile.close();
  }

  else returnValue = "Unable to open file"; 

return returnValue;

}
```

Comment: We don't need most of the code you've given, pretty sure, but we do need an error message you've received. Please add it to the question.

Comment: This does not work: `char returnValue[cipher.size()]; ... return returnValue;`. It is allocated on the stack. Once the function returns the data goes away. Also, `char*` return types never work as expected unless they have an accompanying length due to embedded NULL's. Cipher text will take on all values, including 0x00. You should probably just return `cipher` or `recover` (depending on the function).