# Invalid PKCS #7 block padding found when using Crypto++

Tags: c++, encryption, crypto++, pkcs#7

We are using the code below with the Crypto++ library. We need to encrypt and decrypt `char*`. Encryption is working fine without any issue and we are able to get the cipher text. But getting an error while decrypting as "invalid pkcs #7 block padding found". What could be the issue...?

Encryption Block:

```
char* cspl_crypto::encrypt_rijndael(byte key[], byte iv[], int keysize, char plainText[], int plainTextSize)
{
    vector<byte> cipher;

    std::vector<byte> plain(plainText, plainText + plainTextSize);

    CBC_Mode<AES>::Encryption enc; 
    enc.SetKeyWithIV(key, keysize, iv, keysize);

    // Make room for padding
    cipher.resize(plain.size()+AES::BLOCKSIZE);
    ArraySink cs(&cipher[0], cipher.size());

    ArraySource(plain.data(), plain.size(), true,
        new StreamTransformationFilter(enc, new Redirector(cs)));

    // Set cipher text length now that its known
    cipher.resize(cs.TotalPutLength());
    char returnValue[cipher.size()];
    copy(cipher.begin(), cipher.end(), returnValue);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Decyption Block:

```
char* cspl_crypto::decrypt_rijndael(byte key[], byte iv[], int keysize, char cipher[], int size )
{
    std::vector<byte> v(cipher, cipher + size);
    vector<byte> recover;
    CBC_Mode<AES>::Decryption dec;
    dec.SetKeyWithIV(key, keysize, iv, keysize);

    // Recovered text will be less than cipher text
    recover.resize(v.size());
    ArraySink rs(&recover[0], recover.size());

    ArraySource(v.data(), v.size(), true,
        new StreamTransformationFilter(dec, new Redirector(rs)));

    // Set recovered text length now that its known
    recover.resize(rs.TotalPutLength());

    char returnValue[recover.size()];
    copy(recover.begin(), recover.end(), returnValue);

    return returnValue;
}
```

Comment: This is the same as your other question, including the same mistakes like returning a stack based character array and using a `char*` as a return type. Possible duplicate of [CPP + Cryptopp + Block padding error while decrypting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47474980/cpp-cryptopp-block-padding-error-while-decrypting)

Comment: *"Encryption is working fine without any issue"* - Actually, encryption is broke but you are not learning about it until you go to decrypt.